# Replacement for diff() for multiple columns

Tags: r, diff, xts, zoo

diff() calculates the difference between values in a vector at a specified lag.
Is there an equivalent function that works on two vectors? For example, I have:

```
v1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3)
v2 = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)
```

I need to calculate the difference between each value of v1 and v2 at lag 1. That would be:

```
(2 - 5), (3 - 4), (4 - 3)...
```

This can be achieved using combinations of head()/tails() on the 2 vectors, but I was wondering if there is already a function that can do the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no base function I know of to do this but as gsk3 pointed out the taRifx package has this capability.  I would advise against calling a package to do something this simple:  You could do:

```
v1[-1] - v2[-length(v2)]
```

Or write your own function for storage in .Rprofile

```
shift.diff <- function(x, y) x[-1] - y[-length(y)]
shift.diff(v1, v2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the `shift` command in the `taRifx` package.

```
library(taRifx)
shift(v1)-v2
```

You'll have to decide what you want to do with the last entry (cycle v1 or just make it NA).  `shift` has options for all of those possibilities, as well as for changing the lag to be something other than 1.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using an xts/zoo time-series object, just subtract the lagged series:

```
x <- .xts(cbind(v1,v2), 1:length(v1))
x$v1-lag(x$v2)
```

Comment: I am using an xts object, so this is exactly what I was looking for. I will have to write an xts FAQ at some point... :)

Comment: @RobertKubrick: I figured, since you're the top questioner for the [xts] tag.  If you're serious about writing a FAQ, I would be happy to help.

Comment: I will prepare a draft as soon as I get some spare time. How can I send you a personal message or email? I don't see any direct contact info on this website.

Comment: @RobertKubrick: my contact info is all over the place: [about.me](http://about.me/joshuaulrich) and [TTR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TTR/) are the two that first come to mind.

Answer (score 2):

The `embed` function will create shifted vectors in matrix form. If you pick the first column it is the unshifted but shortened-by-one-at-the-end vector and the second column is the shifted and shortened-by-one-at-the-beginning vector.

```
embed(v1,2)[,1] -embed(v2,2)[,2]
#[1] -3 -1  1  3  2

embed(v1, 2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    1
[2,]    3    2
[3,]    4    3
[4,]    5    4
[5,]    3    5
```